# Does immunity to a keyword in a multi-effect power confer immunity to the whole ability or only part of it?

Tags: dnd-4e, keywords, immunities

For instance, consider a character who is immune to fear, adjacent to a Sibriex Chain Master, which has the aura:

> **Sibriex Horror** *(fear, psychic)✦Aura 3*
>   Any enemy that ends its turn
>   within the aura takes 15 psychic damage and is slowed until the end of
>   its next turn

or is targeted by the following attack power from a Tormenting Ghost:

> **Burst of Terror** *(standard; recharge [5], [6] ) ✦ Fear, Necrotic*
>    Close burst 5; targets enemies; +24 vs. Will; 1d8 + 9 necrotic damage,
>   the target is pushed 5 squares, and the target is dazed and
>   immobilized (save ends both).

Does the fear immunity let the character ignore just the slowing effect in the aura, or the damage also? And in the second example, is everything but the damage ignored due to the fear immunity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to page 225 of the *Rules Compendium (RC):*

> If a creature is immune to charm, fear, illusion, or poison, **it is unaffected by the non-damaging effects of a *power*** that has that keyword.

An aura however is not a *power.*<sup>1</sup> It's just "a continuous *effect* that emanates from a creature" (RC pg.116). So as a strict reading if a creature with immunity to a keyword comes in contact with an aura that has that keyword, it would still take the full effect from the aura.

It might also be worth noting that condition and damage immunity would still apply when a creature is affected by an aura because it's not specified that those effects have to come from a power for a creature to negate them.

Your second example is a power though, so the character would only take the damage and be unaffected by the push, daze, and immobilised effects.

---

<sup>1: Monster Vault page 8, Traits: monster traits are specifically not powers, and auras that come as part of a trait are just there.</sup>

Comment: You've missed commenting on the second power, which has a non-damaging effect. Also, probably worth noting for readers that condition & damage immunity would still apply when you'd take conditions and damage from an aura.

Comment: If this were true and traits ignore Charm, Fear, etc. immunities, what would be the point of putting the Fear keyword on a trait in the first place?

Comment: @MikeKellogg that might be worth another question of its own but keywords also summarise important aspects of a power or effect. I haven't actually played 4e in ages but as I said, as a strict reading, immunity to a keyword only works with powers. I imagine there'd be something else that interacts with the keywords in traits but as it's not necessary to the answering the question I'm not pouring over every book just to find out what they are.

Comment: Looking at the Rules Compendium more closely, the definition of keywords on page 110 (and every keyword definition below that) always uses the term "power" for what they are applied to, never Aura or Trait, in the same way that the quote you used does. If the quote you used was meant to exclude Auras and Traits, then that should apply for all similar uses, meaning Auras and Traits are not allowed to have keywords. Since that is clearly false, it naturally extends that the interpretation of using "power" in your quote as a limitation is also incorrect.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Unfortunately that information -- what that keyword does -- is key to making this answer complete.